# How can i count total documents and also grouped counts simultanously in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a dataset in mongodb collection named `visitorsSession` like

```
{ip : 192.2.1.1,country : 'US', type : 'Visitors',date : '2019-12-15T00:00:00.359Z'},
{ip : 192.3.1.8,country : 'UK', type : 'Visitors',date : '2019-12-15T00:00:00.359Z'},
{ip : 192.5.1.4,country : 'UK', type : 'Visitors',date : '2019-12-15T00:00:00.359Z'},
{ip : 192.8.1.7,country : 'US', type : 'Visitors',date : '2019-12-15T00:00:00.359Z'},
{ip : 192.1.1.3,country : 'US', type : 'Visitors',date : '2019-12-15T00:00:00.359Z'}
```

I am using this `mongodb` aggregation

```
[{$match: {
  nsp : "/hrm.sbtjapan.com",
  creationDate : {
  $gte: "2019-12-15T00:00:00.359Z",
  $lte: "2019-12-20T23:00:00.359Z"
 },
 type : "Visitors"
 }}, {$group: {
 _id : "$country",
 totalSessions : {
   $sum: 1
  }

  }}, {$project: {
    _id : 0,
    country : "$_id",
    totalSessions : 1
   }}, {$sort: {
  country: -1
 }}]
```

using above `aggregation` i am getting results like this

```
[{country : 'US',totalSessions  : 3},{country : 'UK',totalSessions  : 2}]
```

But i also total visitors also along with result like `totalVisitors : 5`
How can i do this in `mongodb aggregation` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$facet` aggregation stage to calculate *total visitors* as well as *visitors by country* in a single pass:

```
db.visitorsSession.aggregate( [
  {
      $match: {
          nsp : "/hrm.sbtjapan.com",
          creationDate : {
              $gte: "2019-12-15T00:00:00.359Z",
              $lte: "2019-12-20T23:00:00.359Z"
          },
          type : "Visitors"
      }
  },
  { 
      $facet: {
            totalVisitors: [
                { 
                    $count: "count" 
                }
            ],
            countrySessions: [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id : "$country", 
                        sessions : { $sum: 1 }
                    }
                },
                { 
                    $project: { 
                        country: "$_id", 
                        _id: 0, 
                        sessions: 1 
                    } 
                }
            ],
      }
  },
 { 
      $addFields: { 
          totalVisitors: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$totalVisitors.count" , 0 ] },
      } 
  }
] )
```

The output:

```
{
        "totalVisitors" : 5,
        "countrySessions" : [
                {
                        "sessions" : 2,
                        "country" : "UK"
                },
                {
                        "sessions" : 3,
                        "country" : "US"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: this query runs perfectly but result i am getting is not exactly same as you mentioned. I am getting result like this
`totalVisitors : [{count : 5}, countrySessions : [{sesions : 2,country : 'UK'},{sesions : 3,country : 'US'}]`

Comment: I think you ran the query  _without_ the last `$addFields` stage; include it and get the result as in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could be better off with two queries to do this.

To save the two db round trips following aggregation can be used which IMO is kinda verbose (and might be little expensive if documents are very large) to just count the documents.

**Idea:** Is to have a [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) at the top to count documents and preserve the original documents using [**`$push`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) and **`$$ROOT`**. And then before other matches/filter ops [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the created array of original docs.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docsCount: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      originals: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$originals"
  },
  { $match: "..." }, //and other stages on `originals` which contains the source documents
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$originals.country",
      totalSessions: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      totalVisitors: {
        $first: "$docsCount"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Sample O/P:** [Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tub53vcgSxM)

```
[
  {
    "_id": "UK",
    "totalSessions": 2,
    "totalVisitors": 5
  },
  {
    "_id": "US",
    "totalSessions": 3,
    "totalVisitors": 5
  }
]
```